# Docker on Windows Server not stable

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016, windows-server-2019

I'm using Docker Desktop on Windows 10 with Windows containers without any problems.

Now, I also want to use Docker on Windows Server, I've tried Windows Server 2016 and Windows Server 2019 so far.

I can install Docker Enterprise without any problems, I can start a container based on the nanoserver image without problems. But after a while (something between 10 and 20 minutes), the container terminates.

Has anyone seen such a behavior? Is this the expected behavior?

The Windows is

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Standard
OS Version:                10.0.17763 N/A Build 17763
```

I've installed Docker with this commands:

```
Install-WindowsFeature -Name Containers
Uninstall-WindowsFeature Windows-Defender
Restart-Computer -Force

Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -Repository PSGallery -Force
Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force -RequiredVersion 19.03

Start-Service docker
```

Afterwards I can use the `docker ps` command and I can start the nanoserver image using the command

```
docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809 cmd
```

The container starts and I can use it.

But when I leave it open and do nothing within, after a while it terminated.
The same happens with the image `servercore:ltsc2019` and images derived from that one.

Comment: What happens if you remove "cmd" from the end of your run command?